# JSON data deserialization

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I get this JSON data from front-end:

```
user    {"idUser":5,"fullname":"Bob Marley", "birthday":"1990-12-14", "login":"b.marley", "password":"none","dateCreate":"2014-10-09 15:01","grp":{"idGrp":"2","nameGrp":"client"}}
```

I want to do deserialization these data in java:

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idUser;
    private String fullname;
    private Date birthday;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private Date dateCreate;
    private Grp grp;
    //getters and setters
```

**UserDeserializer.java**

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        User user = new User();
        user.setIdUser(jObject.get("idUser").getAsInt());
        user.setFullname(jObject.get("fullname").getAsString());

        try {
            Date birthday = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(jObject.get("birthday").getAsString());
            user.setBirthday(birthday);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }

        user.setLogin(jObject.get("login").getAsString());
        user.setPassword(jObject.get("password").getAsString());

        try {
            Date dateCreate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(jObject.get("dateCreate").getAsString());
            user.setDateCreate(dateCreate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }

        Grp grp = context.deserialize(jObject.get("grp"), Grp.class);
        user.setGrp(grp);    
        return user;
    }
}
```

**UserEdit.java**

```
public class UserEdit extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        User user = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("user"), User.class);
```

And I get this error at the last row of the UserEdit.java:

> 04-Nov-2014 21:30:44.003 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Servlet UserEdit] in context with path [] threw exception
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1990-12-14   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)     at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:691)  at
>   com.gmail.zigfridus.UserEdit.doGet(UserEdit.java:24)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1990-12-14"  at
>   java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:79)
>     ... 32 more

It says that error is because of birthday date, but that date looks like normal.

Please, help me.

Comment: The `user` at the beginning of the JSON `user    {"idUser":5,` makes this ill-formed JSON. Is there really a `user` at the beginning?

Comment: @Vinze: which one exactly are you referring to, that deals with "any problem"?

Comment: @zigfridus are you sure your `deserialize` method is called?

Comment: @JonathanM Yes, there is really `user` at the beginning: `http://localhost:8080/UserEdit?user=%7B%22idUser%22%3A5%2C%22...`

Comment: @njzk2 I wrongly read the question, I think... removed my comment.
No entry of the stack seems in user code, so it may be a misuse of the API...

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not sure that my deserialize method called, because in the debugging mode any of their rows hadn't called before error.

Comment: So, when you debug it, what does `jObject.get("birthday").getAsString()` look like?

Comment: (I'm guessing that you never even get to your birthday parsing code, because you failed to tell GSON you'd parse it yourself, so it's trying to parse it based on its "standard" format.)

Comment: @HotLicks In debugger mode this row `jObject.get("birthday").getAsString()` doesn't call. Even first row `JsonObject jObject = json.getAsJsonObject();` of the deserialize() method doesn't call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

You are creating a new `GsonBuilder`, effectively dismissing the one you just configured. Use

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

to use the gsonBuilder configured with the user deserializer.

Comment: It was a really stupid mistake. How I didn't see it, I don't understand... Thank You very much for your help! )

Answer (score 1):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` as your simple date format. I know you don't have hours, minutes and seconds, but I don't believe that it accepts it without them.

Comment: I added dummy time to the birthday: `"birthday":"1990-12-14 17:08:44"`. But it didn't help. I got the same error: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1990-12-14 17:08:44`

Comment: Try not adding the dummy time. It will come out zeroes, but It should do the correct format on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add values for hh:mm:ss in order to instantiate an acceptable date format. You obviously aren't concerned with the time and in this case I would suggest simply using 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems the use of DateTypeAdapter in the API internal bind...
I'm not familiar with this library but maybe your UserDeserializer is not correctly configured in the API/framework and default one is used (and birthday is Date in the bean to deserialize)